# Induction charging - What kind of calculations are involved?

Tags: power, induction

I am designing a simple locking mechanism. The idea is that the locking mechanism cannot be locally powered. In other words, the key (size does not matter) and the lock must interact wirelessly. More importantly, the key must be able to provide the power to turn on the locking mechanism, and open it.

This isn't supposed to be a highly secure and strong system right now, it just needs to be a proof of concept. So, I have decided to hook up a servo to a micrcontroller to actuate the mechanism (probably an ATmega or ATTiny, probably something even lower powered). That's not important, anyway.

I would like to apply the same concept used in those commercially available induction charging stations to this project. I don't need to physically build it yet, but need to know how I can compute the specifics of the induction power transfer system required to power this device. You can consider the power consumption of the lock to be variable, so I'm essentially looking for the equations/concepts involved in this whole science of induction charging in generality.

I have tried searching for technical information, but Google is crowded with commercial fluff on why induction charging is cool and whatnot. I need to know how it works, and what I would need to apply it to any situation. Of course, if you have any suggestions for low power locking mechanisms, please add them to your answer.

Comment: Can someone explain why there are so many votes to close this please?

Comment: I'd guess it's because it's such a broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inductive chargers are just transformers with poor coupling or antennas with good coupling. The thing that makes them work is [electromagnetic induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction), and if you can understand that, and how transformers and antennas work, then inductive charging will make sense.